# Unable to Determine Error in QGIS Log Message Panel

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, error

A plugin is built for our road data network in qgis which basically splits roads at intersection and use grass `v.clean` algorithm, this tool runs smoothly until now, but now it's not splitting road, from snip can anyone gives me idea what is wrong, QGIS version 3.4 stable and OS is Windows 10.

[image]

[image: QGIS Log Message Panel]

Comment: Go to the `Python warning` tab and check which line in in whatever plugin file that error appears. Then please type in the message in the post instead of a screenshot.

Comment: but Python warning tab doesn't show any plugin related error, the error is shown in processing, postgis, grass and ogr tab, means its more like processing related error